# How to write physics equation in HTML

Tags: html, physics, equation

I'm having a problem to represent below physics equation using just HTML tag

[image]

So, How to represent above equation into HTML without using mathjax...??
Thanks in advance :)

I have tried this code :

```
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">A sin &omega;( t - </td>
          <td style="border-bottom:solid 1px">x</td>
          <td> )</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>            
            <td>v</td>
          </tr>

      </tbody>
</table>
```

But I don't know how to make it works

Comment: It's unclear if what you can't do is *to represent* the equation or *solve* the equation...

Comment: Soorry... I have updated my question, I just want to represent that equation using HTML without mathjax... :)

Comment: While under fire due to bad browser implementationes (e.g. WebKit), I see MathML as an alternative you could try. Also there is LaTex -> Html converters out there. Not sure though, how the generated Html is working and which libraries they use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully [this](https://jsfiddle.net/q250dun1/) might set you in the right direction:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>y = A sin &omega;</td>
      <td style="font-size:200%">(</td>
      <td>t -</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom:solid 1px black">x</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>v</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td style="font-size:200%">)</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There is a lot you can achieve with nested tables.

Comment: Waaaw... Cool... Thanks Mr.Alastair... I will adapt your answer to fullfill my need :)

Answer (score 0):

[MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) is your best shot.. If you are keen to do this without MathJax this [link](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/) will help you

Comment: I'm not really familiar with mathjax >.<

Comment: I'm reading it now... But I'm a little bit confused... :D
Lemme take a moment... fiuuh...
Thanks btw Mr. Tony Stark... :D

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for Mr. Alastair's answer, I finally can represent it to HTML like this :

```
<table>
      <tbody>        
          <td>y = A sin &omega;</td>
          <td style="font-size:200%">(</td>
          <td>t -</td>
          <td><table>
             <tr><td style="border-bottom:solid 1px black">x</td></tr>
             <tr><td>v</td></tr>
          </table>
          </td>
          <td style="font-size:200%">)</td>
          <td> = A sin </td>
          <td style="font-size:200%">(</td>
          <td>&omega;t -</td>
          <td>
            <table>
             <tr><td style="border-bottom:solid 1px black">&omega;</td></tr>
             <tr><td>v</td></tr>
            </table>
            </td>
          td> x </td>
         <td style="font-size:200%">)</td>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]